# Python Classes in 2 Files [Learn Python the Hard Way]

Tags: python

Hey guys,
I'm currently completing Zed Shaw's ["Learn Python the Hard Way"](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/static/LearnPythonTheHardWay.pdf) and I've been struggling with Exercise 43, which instructs the learner to make a game. For simplicity, I am attempting to rewrite the previous exercise that has a class `Game` and some functions:
`__init__`, `play`, `death`, and four more for each "room" in the game.

I was able to copy and modify the code for various conditions, but I wanted to try to split the code in to two files: one file containing a class `PrincessRoom` to be the sole room for the game, and the other containing the bulk of the old code `play` and `death`.

From `ex43.py`

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint
from ex43princess import PrincessRoom

class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.quips = [
            "You died. You suck.",
            "Hey, you died. Look at that.",
            "You lose. I win. End.",
        ]
        self.start = start

    def play(self):
        next = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            room = getattr(self, next)
            next = room()

    def death(self):
        print self.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
        exit(1)

a_game = Game("princess")
a_game.play()
```

From `ex43princess.py`

```
class PrincessRoom(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def princess(self):
        print "text here"

        raw_input("> ")

        if raw_input == 1:
            return 'eat_it'
        else:
            return 'death'

    def eat_it(self):
        print "text here"
```

When I run the code, here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex43-2.py", line 29, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "ex43-2.py", line 21, in play
    room = getattr(self, next)
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'princess'``
```

Now I'm not too solid on why the original code had `a_game` initialized with `a_game = Game("princess")` but I'm pretty sure it's directly related to why it has me use `room = getattr(self, next)`. But this is where my understanding falters.

If memory serves, it would appear that `Game` object isn't inheriting properly from ex43princess.py... right?

If any one could help me understand what is happening here I would be much appreciative.

Thanks!
Josh

Comment: where is your game class are you creating a new `PrincessRoom` object? It's complaining because it's trying to access Princess and it's just a string not an actual object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I'm not familiar with the book and hence with the context of the question, so my answer refers to the displayed code only*

The problem here isn't splitting the code to two files. As far as I can see, the `PrincessRoom` class in its own file presents no real problem.

`Game` can't find the `princess` method, and it doesn't have one. Perhaps it should've inherited from `PrincessRoom`?

That said, I'm not sure that it makes sense logically to inherit a class named `Game` from a class named `PrincessRoom`. A better approach IMHO would be *aggregation* - i.e. keep a collection of rooms as an instance variable of `Game` and access them through it. Inheritance should be really reserved to *is-a* relations. You should ask yourself, whether "Game is-a PrincessRoom" makes sense. It probably doesn't. What does make sense is "Game has-a PrincessRoom", and *has-a* is represented by aggregation in OOP.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right. I was looking for a way to learn how to use multiple files but it turns out I've just completely bungled it. And thanks for the 'is-a' vs. 'has-a' differentiation - it explains one of the later chapters. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty version of exercise 43. [Here](http://python.pastebin.com/iE4a7JSK). The key is that you are just trying to instantiate the PrincessRoom objects but you can't do it with just a string like you are trying to do.

Comment: Here's a slightly more complex one if you think you can handle it :) http://python.pastebin.com/T06PVjiq

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for these. I didn't initially understand what was going on with the second one but I'm pretty sure I've got most of it down... Thanks again for something to study!